# Algorithm: "Minimum" maximum flow with extra capacities

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

**Problem:**

Suppose there is a graph, a source and a sink. Each edge has a capacity and an extra capacity that it can hold. If sink needs a defined amount of flow `F`, find a total extra capacity needed `E` so that maximum flow from source to sink is greater than or equal to `F` and flow in each edge that has nonzero flow.

I don't know how to solve this variation of maximum flow problem. It is obvious that if maximum flow I find without extra capacities is greater than or equal to `F`, then there is no need for extra capacity. If it is less than `F`, should I add extra capacity in each edge one by one and find max flow again till I find the closest one to `F` (if it is not enough, then take in pairs, triplets, etc.)? This solution seems inefficient to me.

Comment: How are you measuring total extra capacity? The sum of the extra capacities used across each edge? The maximum extra capacity used across an edge?

Comment: E is a sum of extra capacities used across each edge

Comment: it's my question, this one migrated too late